# Points in a triangular lattice at the same distance from the origin and "breaking of symmetry"

Tags: number-theory, integer-lattices, discrete-geometry

**Introduction**

I was trying to simulate what would happen to a certain physical system taking place in a triangular lattice (the physical details are not relevant to the discussion), when I came across a question that I could not answer and I am not familiar enough with the underlying maths to even know what to look for online.

Consider the ($2\mathrm{D}$) triangular lattice spaned by the two units vectors $e_1 = (1, 0)$ and $e_2 = (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$.

**How I came across my problem (skip if only interested in the actual maths)**

I was interested in a two-variable function $f(\overrightarrow{x_1}, \overrightarrow{x_2})$, with $\overrightarrow{x_1}$ and $\overrightarrow{x_2}$ belonging to the lattice. The function is translationally and rotationally invariant so that it only depends on the norm of the difference $f(\overrightarrow{x_1}, \overrightarrow{x_2}) = g(| \overrightarrow{x_1}- \overrightarrow{x_2}|)$. For simplicity, I will assume in the following that $\overrightarrow{x_1} = 0$ and note $\tilde{f}(\overrightarrow{x}) = f(\overrightarrow{0}, \overrightarrow{x}),$ with $\overrightarrow{x}$ in the lattice

My (poorly-written) code was giving the expected results for $\overrightarrow{x} = e_1, \overrightarrow{x} = e_2, \overrightarrow{x} = e_1 + e_2, \overrightarrow{x} = 2 e_1, \dots$ In fact, if you regroup together all vectors $\overrightarrow{x}$ within a same distance of the origin, and you sort the groups ($X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n, \dots)$ from the smallest to the largest distance (so $X_1$ would be the six sites nearest to the origin, $X_2$ the six next-nearest sites, and so on and so forth), I had the right results for all $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$ all the way up to $X_{19}$. But for some reason it was breaking down at $X_{20}$. I first thought that this was because my code was not good for large distances, but it worked again for $X_{21}$, $X_{22}, \dots$ so this was really strange

To help visualize this I plotted the different $X_i$'s for $i$ from $1$ to $30$ as seen below (sorry for the horrible color choice but it is to help distinguish groups that are close to each other):

[image: The 30 groups of sites closest to the origin]

The troublesome sites are the ones that are circled in red. After a while trying to figure out what was wrong, I realized that my code (I told you it was poorly written) is probably making the implicit assumption that all sites within a group were "equivalent" in some sense (any of them can be transformed into any other from the same group by a rotation of angle $k \times 60^{\circ}$, $k \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \}$ around the origin, and/or a reflexion with respect to the X or Y axis). But it is easy to see that this is not the case for $X_{20}$, as this group contains $18$ vectors instead of $6$ or $12$. This comes from the fact that $3 e_1 + 5 e_2$ and $7 e_2$ have the same norm while not being related by a rotation of $k \times 60^{\circ}$ and/or reflexion. I do not know the next time it happens, but from looking at the first $30$ groups of vectors, this seems to be the only occurence.

**Actual maths**

I guess this is a well-known problem in group theory/number theory, but can you find all points $\overrightarrow{x_1}$, $\overrightarrow{x_2}$ in a triangular lattice that are at the same distance from the origin while breaking the symmetries of the original lattice? How does this expand to different type of lattices and/or different dimensions? The closest thing that I am familiar with is the equivalent problem for a square lattice, which is to find all non-trivial integer solutions to the equation:

$$ a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + d^2, \quad (a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{N}^4$$

For instance, $(6, 8, 10, 0)$ is an acceptable solution. But I am looking here for solutions in the case of a triangular lattice, and possibly how to generalize it to different lattice types.

Comment: if all you need is $u^2 + uv + v^2 = x^2 + xy + y^2,$ that can be described

Comment: That would be one way to phrase it, yes. I am not sure however how to rule out the trivial solutions (rotation of $k \times 60^{\circ}$ and/or reflexion w. r. t $X$ or $Y$).

Comment: For the square lattice, you might want to look at the [Gauss circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem) and the [sum of two squares function $r_2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares_function#Particular_cases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Dickson, 1929:

The number of representations of any positive $n$ by $q=x^2 +xy+y^2$ is $6E(n),$ where $E(n)$ is the excess of the number of divisors $3h+1$ over the number of divisors $3h+2.$ If $n=2^k m,$ then we have $E(n) = 0$ when $k$ is odd, but when $k$ is even we have $E(n) = E(m).$

I should add that the situation with the prime $2$ is the same as the situation with prime $5$ or $11$ or any $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3.$  If, in factoring the number $n,$ the exponent of such a prime $p$ is odd, there are no representations at all. If the exponent of such $p$ is even, dividing by $p^2$ does not change the number of representations, so we may keep dividing by such $p^2$ until the only prime factors are $3$ itself and any $q \equiv 1 \pmod 3. $ Multiplying by $3$ does not change the number of representations (needs a little proof) so we keep dividing by that as well. In the end, we are asking for the number of divisors of a number that is a product of primes $q_j \equiv 1 \pmod 3.$ Then multiply by $6$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've found it very useful. I knew that it must have been studied before but I didn't know what to look for. As for the initial question, it seems that there are $24$ solutions for $n = 91 = 7 \times 13$ (not sure if it "breaks the symmetry" though). The next time we see $18$ solutions is for $n = 147 = 3 \times 49$. Interestingly, there are also first $30$ solutions for $n = 2901 = 7^4$, which clearly breaks the symmetry of the initial lattice.

Comment: Do you know if this result can be generalized to higher dimension lattices (for instance, hexagonal compact or face-centered cubic in $3\mathrm{D}$), or does it need to be solved case by case?

Comment: @QuantumApple Entirely dependent on dimension. Dimensions 2 and 4 are fairly nice. See http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/  She also notes that many theta series are given at the OEIS. "The sequence 1, 6, 12, 8, 6, 24, 24, ... for example is the theta series of the simple cubic lattice."

Comment: @QuantumApple you may have mistyped $7^4$. Should be $2401$.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be the prettiest one: for
$$  u^2 + uv + v^2 = x^2 + xy+y^2,  $$
take coprime integers $p,q,r,s$  and
$$  u = rs+ps- rq  $$
$$  v = pq-ps + rq  $$
$$  x = pq -rs + rq  $$
$$  y = -pq+rs+ps  $$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
      u  \\
      v    \\
      x    \\
      y    \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
      0   &   1   &   1 &    -1 \\
      1   &   0  &   -1 &     1 \\
      1   &  -1  &    0  &    1 \\
     -1   &   1  &    1   &   0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
      pq   \\
      rs    \\
      ps    \\
      rq    \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

---

```
parisize = 4000000, primelimit = 500000
?   u = 0*p*q+r*s+p*s- r*q ;   v = p*q+ 0*r*s-p*s +r*q ;     x = p*q -r*s +0*p*s+ r*q ;    y = -p*q+r*s+p*s + 0* r*q  ;
? u
%2 = s*p + (-r*q + s*r)
? v
%3 = (q - s)*p + r*q
? x
%4 = q*p + (r*q - s*r)
? y
%5 = (-q + s)*p + s*r
? u^2 + u*v + v^2
%6 = (q^2 - s*q + s^2)*p^2 + (r*q^2 - s*r*q + s^2*r)*p + (r^2*q^2 - s*r^2*q + s^2*r^2)
? f = u^2 + u*v + v^2
%7 = (q^2 - s*q + s^2)*p^2 + (r*q^2 - s*r*q + s^2*r)*p + (r^2*q^2 - s*r^2*q + s^2*r^2)
? g = x^2 + x*y + y^2
%8 = (q^2 - s*q + s^2)*p^2 + (r*q^2 - s*r*q + s^2*r)*p + (r^2*q^2 - s*r^2*q + s^2*r^2)
? f - g
%9 = 0
? 
?
```

---

Comment: It's surprising that neither the sequence $2,3,4,7,9,12,13,\ldots$ of numbers representable in this way, nor the sequence of the counts $6,6,6,0,0,12,0,6,0,0,6,\ldots$ of the representations (or the same divided by $6$) is in OEIS. I was hoping to find a closed form there, in analogy to the [sum of two squares function $r_2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares_function#Particular_cases). Do you think your representation could be used to find one? Or should that be the subject of a new question?

Comment: @joriki, if you want a count, there is a closed form formula in Dickson, Inroduction to Theory of Numbers, about 1929 and often reprinted. Page 80, exercise 2.

Comment: @joriki Thank you for reminding me of the existence of OEIS. I went to check it and in fact I've found the exact the sequence you were looking for (only it is divided by six). It is in fact related to Will Jaggy's comment above and the other answer. You can check it out: https://oeis.org/A002324